# voice dictation for watch kit (Apple Watch)

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchos-2

The present method am using for voice dictation is little hectic. The method used is “`presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions`”. It follows series of steps for single voice input  "`VoiceInputButton -> SpeakButton -> VoiceInputFromUser -> DoneButton`". I think above procedure consumes more time for single input where it lacks fastness. Please help me if there are some other alternatives to fasten `(VoiceInputButton -> VoiceInputFromUser)` the voice input?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass an empty list of suggestions and set the allowedInputMode to plain, you should go straight to dictation (the suggestion screen will not be displayed).

Comment: Unfortunately, not at this time.